# How does node.js require method interpret relative paths?

Tags: node.js, require

I'm having trouble understanding how node's `require` method is able to resolve relative paths.

Let's say I have a file structure like this:

```
root
|--- main.js
|
|--- importantUtilities.js
|
|--- apps
     |
     |--- app1.js
```

If both `/root/main.js` and `/root/apps/app1.js` want to require `/root/importantUtilities.js`, they parameterize the `require` function differently:

```
// File: /root/main.js

...
require('./importantUtilities.js');
...

// File: /root/apps/app1.js:

...
require('../importantUtilities.js');
...
```

There is no need to prepend `__dirname`, and I don't see how `require` functions without this piece of information.

**How can `require` be implemented to return the same file for different file descriptors?**

EDIT: The fact that the following example works also blows my mind (using the same file structure):

```
// File: /root/main.js:

...
module.exports.getUtilities = function() { return require('./importantUtilities.js'); };
var utilities = module.exports.getUtilities(); // Works fine
...

// File: /root/apps/app1.js:

...
var main = require('../main.js');
var utilities = main.getUtilities(); // Works fine
...
```

It seems that `require` is not even determining the base path from the calling scope; it's more so that somehow every occurrence of `require` in the source code is bound with the source code's filepath information. Is this correct?

**How does any of this work??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every occurrence of require in the source code is bound with the source code's filepath information

Yes, that's exactly correct. More precise, according to [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together):

> require(X) from module at path Y
>
> 3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
>
>    a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)

i.e. it concatenates current file's path with the path being `require`d.

Comment: So it's almost like pre-processing! Exactly the docs link I was looking for :D